# Проверка файла на вирусы

Tags: php, debian

Есть ли-какие либо способы проверки файла на вирусы, после загрузки на сервер?

Пользователь загружает файл на сервер, при переходе на страницу с файлом, мне нужно его проверить на наличие вирусов, и вывести текстовую информацию, о том что данный файл заражен, и администрация не рекомендует его скачивать.

ОС на сервере Debian 7. Попробовал ClamAV + расширение для PHP. Толку от него ноль, так как обычный Троян обнаружить не может

Comment: @rnddev, а от большинства антивирусов толку почти ноль (и от тех, что за деньги, тоже).

По большому счету, все это для самоуспокоения.

--

Кстати, а какие антивирусы **поймали** тот тестовый троян, с которым ClamAV не справился?

Comment: @avp через virustotal и clamav его видит. 
ClamAV  WIN.Trojan.Agent-249018

Comment: пробовал virustotal api 2, вообще ужасно, то что файл стоит долго в очереди, предлагают приобрести ключ за деньги, но у меня нет желания вкладывать в не коммерческий проект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно, нужно проверить файл антивирусом и разобрать его ответ. Каким именно - выбирайте сами. Из неочевидных решений:

1) Установленный где-то drwebd, скормить файл ему можно по собственному протоколу, оттуда же получить ответ. При этом сам файл не обязательно гонять по сокетам, если он доступен демону по файловой системе. В поставку drwebd входят и описание протокола, и примеры клиентов с исходниками. Это решение может оказаться лучше тем, что не нужно на каждый файл запускать отдельный сканер, который будет каждый раз инициализироваться, грузить базы, можно обслуживать очереди из проверяемых файлов без размножения лишних процессов, и т.д.

2) Сформировать `multipart/form-data` на страницу http://online.drweb.com/result/ и распарсить ответ. Подробности POST - в формах, которые можно скачать [здесь](http://www.freedrweb.com/for+web+sites/) (фактически там кроме одного `input type="file" name="file"` ничего и не нужно). Для такого варианта вам вообще не требуется устанавливать свой антивирус.

Наверняка аналогичные решения есть и у других производителей антивирусов.

---

> Пользователь загружает файл на сервер, при переходе на страницу с файлом, мне нужно его проверить на наличие вирусов,

Только одно замечание. В общем случае файл нужно проверять сразу же после загрузки, и уже только после этого принимать решение: складывать его в доступную область и выдавать ссылку, или нет. То есть никакого "перехода на страницу с файлом" если он заражён быть не должно.

Comment: + https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/
+ http://virusscan.jotti.org

Comment: >Только одно замечание. В общем случае файл нужно проверять сразу же >после загрузки, и уже только после этого принимать решение: >складывать его в доступную область и выдавать ссылку, или нет. То >есть никакого "перехода на страницу с файлом" если он заражён быть >не должно.

меня не интересует что будут качать юзеры, мне главное их предупредить

Comment: @Etki интересные пруфы. спасибо

Comment: тем не менее, правильная архитектурно и просто удобная точка проверки - обработка принятой формы. Причем сама проверка может быть запущена параллельно с этой обработкой.

Comment: @rnddev, а @klopp и не про то, что именно будут качать юзеры и предупреждения, он про архитектуру.

Answer (score 0):

[Антивирус Касперского для Linux File Server](http://www.kaspersky.ru/business-security/linux-file-server-antivirus)

> В крупных компаниях в одной сети часто присутствуют файловые серверы, работающие под управлением различных платформ. В таких случаях задача защиты информации становится особенно актуальной. Антивирус Касперского для Linux File Server входит в предлагаемую «Лабораторией Касперского» обновленную линейку продуктов, решений и услуг для гетерогенных сетей.

Comment: @VasyOk, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.